# Why can't I run commands by themselves in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

It would be great if we could run commands in the terminal during simulation. Just like in JavaScript where you can enter commands and get output. Why is there no such functionality in programming for iOS?

Comment: Did you try Playground?!

Comment: What kind of commands? If you're referring to debugging an app, you can set a breakpoint and view variables in the xcode terminal by running `po myVariable`.

If you want to just run swift code, just enter the swift REPL by running `swift` in a terminal.

Or try a Playground

Comment: Read through Apple's docs on Xcode Debugging here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/about_debugging_w_xcode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH10-SW1 - then search for tutorials on using the debug console. You can call functions, evaluate objects, set properties... on and on and on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Only interpreted languages can execute code at runtime. Compiled languages cannot. Since swift is a compiled language it cannot execute code at runtime.**

*Examples Of Interpreted Languages*

- Java
- JavaScript
- PHP
- Perl
- Python
- Ruby

*Examples Of Compiled Languages*

- C
- C++
- C#
- Objective-C
- Pascal
- Scala
- Swift

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I needed.